# jquery ui draggable z-index issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Below is the code where I am binding a table row as draggable. However the dragged item appears below the splitter (http://methvin.com/splitter/splitter.js) This issue seems to be with the `z-index`. I tried multiple ways to set the `z-index` of dragged item. However this does not seem to work. The `bindDragAndDrop` method is triggered with the mouse is hovered over the table. Could some one point me what might be the issue ?

```
function bindDragAndDrop(){

    var table = $('TABLE .dataTable');
        table.find('TR TD.columnClass').bind('mousedown', function() {
            table.disableSelection();
        }).bind('mouseup', function() {
            table.enableSelection();
        }).draggable({
         helper: function(event) {
         return $('<div div="dragDiv" class="drag-table-item"><table></table></div>').find('table').append($(event.target).closest('tr').clone())
 .end().insertAfter(table);
            },
            cursorAt: {
                left: -5,
                bottom: 5
            },
            cursor: 'move',
            distance: 10,
            delay: 100,
            scope: 'cart-item',
            revert: 'invalid'
        });         
 }
```

Comment: Hello, it is hard to help you without a live example. Can you set up your problem using : http://jsfiddle.net ? I had this kind of problem some trouble few weeks ago and I figured it out using a custom helper set the greatest page z-index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried setting the zIndex multiple ways it did not work. As shown below the **appendTo("body")**    resolved this issue

```
 return $('<div class="drag-table-item"><table></table></div>').find('table').append($(event.target).closest('tr').clone()).end().insertAfter(table).appendTo("body");
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved a similar problem for me. Is it a hack, because I don't realy get it...